# How to use sandbox accounts in iOS 11?

Tags: app-store-connect, in-app-purchase, testflight

[These are the official directions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html) for testing with sandbox accounts:

1. Set up test user accounts within Users and Roles in iTunes Connect
2. Clear any account information stored on your test device. In settings, go to the Store settings. Click the Sign Out button. *(Note that iOS 11 does not have a section named "Store" in the settings. I go into **iTunes & App Store** and sign out from there)*
3. Connect the test device to your Mac.
4. In Xcode, set your test device as your scheme's destination
5. Open your app, and perform your in-app purchase product testing
6. Use your test account credentials to test the purchase.

I have tried following these instructions, but I'm not able to complete step 6. When I launch the app after signing my Apple ID out of the App Store, it asks me to enter the password for my Apple ID. It does not give me the option of entering a different account. I don't see any way to use a sandbox account.

Are Apple's instructions out of date? Should I be doing something differently?

**Followup note:**

It turned out that for whatever reason, trying to use sandbox accounts on my iPod Touch is a lost cause. However, I am able to use sandbox accounts on my iPad Air 2. But another team member is *not* able to use sandbox accounts on *any* of his devices, experiencing the same issue I outlined.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your device after step #2?  I'm just thinking it might have cached your credentials somewhere.

Comment: @fsb D'oh! That did the trick. Want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @fsb I spoke too soon; it worked once and then went back to asking for the password for my primary Apple ID, even though the iTunes & App Store settings page shows I'm now logged in with the sandbox account.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you have different versions of iOS. As per [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchase_transactions#3524803) documentation:

- For iOS 11 or earlier — Sign out of the App Store in Settings, then build and run your app from Xcode.
- For iOS 12 or later — Don't sign out of the App Store; simply build and run your app from Xcode. Sandbox accounts are stored separately, and you can control your sandbox account directly on-device in Settings.

Additional related documentation:

- [Test in-app purchases - App Store Connect Help](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7e89e149d)
- [Apple Pay - Sandbox Testing - Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/sandbox-testing/)

Comment: I am having trouble with Sandbox Account section showing up in Settings on some iOS devices (that;s how I landed here). When I figure it out, I will update this answer.